# Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_IRLScannerViewController error in iOS build using Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I am facing an issue while building my iOS project in Xcode. The error message I am getting is "Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_IRLScannerViewController". I have already checked that I have the IRLScannerViewController.h file in my project. Here are some more details:

I am using Xcode 12.5.
I have already tried cleaning the build folder and rebuilding the project.
I have also checked that the IRLScannerViewController library is added in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section of my project.
I have also tried reinstalling the dependencies using Cocoapods by running "pod install" command.
Despite these efforts, I am still getting the same error. Can someone suggest me what could be the issue and how can I fix it? Any help would be appreciated.